# MvvM Cross NullReferenceException from the outset

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying out MvvmCross on my Xamarin project (which I have just created), and I've followed all of the .txt file instructions and I'm trying it for the first time and via my Windows Phone project, but I keep getting an obscure NullReferenceException during some part of the initialisation (this is no inner exception, so have no idea whats broken inside MvvMCross).

Here is the output from the MvvM diagnostics

```
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.04 Setup: PlatformServices start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.06 Setup: MvvmCross settings start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.07 Setup: Singleton Cache start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.07 Setup: Bootstrap actions
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.17 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.20 Setup: CommandHelper start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.22 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.24 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.25 Setup: App start
mvx:Diagnostic:  2.87 Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
mvx:Diagnostic:  2.88 Setup: ViewsContainer start
mvx:Diagnostic:  2.89 Setup: ViewDispatcher start
mvx:Diagnostic:  2.89 Setup: Views start
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Cirrious.CrossCore.DLL
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: please show your setup code

Comment: A stack trace for the exception might also be useful